# Find if a map contains multiple keys

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm new to Clojure and I was wondering if there was a way to test if a map has multiple keys. I've noticed that `contains?` only checks for one key

What i'm trying to do:

```
(def mario 
    {:position {:x 1 :y 2}
     :velocity {:x 2 :y 0}
     :mass 20})

;;Test if mario has a position and a velocity
(contains-many? mario :position :velocity) ;;true

;;Test if mario has a mass and a jump-height
(contains-many? mario :mass :jump-height) ;;false
```

basically, is there a function like `contains-many?` in the clojure library and if not how would you implement the `contains-many?` function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know any function that does that. It is also necessary to define whether you want the map to contain *every* key or just *some* keys. I chose the *every* case, if you wanted the *some* version, just replace `every?` with `some?`.

My direct, not optimized, version is:

```clj
(defn contains-many? [m & ks]
  (every? #(contains? m %) ks))
```

Which has been tested with:

```clj
(deftest a-test
  (testing "Basic test cases"
    (let [m {:a 1 :b 1 :c 2}]
      (is (contains-many? m :a))
      (is (contains-many? m :a :b))
      (is (contains-many? m :a :b :c))
      (is (not (contains-many? m :a :d)))
      (is (not (contains-many? m :a :b :d))))))
```

Edit: Simplified using noisesmith's suggestion

Comment: Cool! Thanks. Yeah, I wanted the function to test if a map had every key. Thanks. Quick question though: What is this syntax: `#(contains? m %)` Is this like currying or pattern-matching or something?

Comment: That is syntactic sugar to create an anonymous function of one argument (which is denoted by %). It is equivalent to `(fn [k] (contains? m k))`. https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/fn

Comment: Cool! Thanks. I see. The syntactic sugar does make it a little more compact and readable.

Comment: simpler version: `(every? #(contains? m %) ks)`

Answer (score 23):

The correct answer was shown, but I would like to point out another elegant solution which assums knowledge about the map values. When you know for sure they are truthy (that is: not `nil` and not `false`):

```
(every? m ks)
```

This is due to the fact that maps are (unary) functions which return the corresponding value to the argument. But note that `({:x nil} :x) => nil`.

Comment: Maps are functions?! Wow! Well, I know for sure that my values are not `nil` but they can be `false`. So, I don't think I can use this trick this time but I'll certainly keep it in mind for the future, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could leverage [`clojure.set/subset?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.set/subset_q)

```clj
(clojure.set/subset?
  #{:position :velocity}
  (set (keys mario)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution using `clojure.set` that works with non-truthy values:

```
(require '[clojure.set :as set])

(defn contains-many? [m & ks]
  (empty? (set/difference (set ks) (set (keys m)))))
```